# Base64 Encoding for multi Variables

Tags: postman

I have a list of 3 environment variables that I want to bind and encode them (Key +value) in base64.
fro examples,
the 3 Variable now are stored as key-value variables and what i need to have is a base64 encode on this:
{
    "VAR1": "313",
    "VAR2": "33344",
    "VAR3": "rovkssj",
}
I guess that should use the script to create the json and encode it.

appreciate your help
Ronen

Answer (score 19):

Postman uses the built-in module `CryptoJS`. This *could* be used to get you close to a solution.

If you add this into the `Pre-request Script` or `Tests` tab and send a request, you will see the output of the Base64 conversation in the Postman Console. In the example I'm getting the 'VAR1' `environment variable` and using this as the value to convert.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")

//Encrypt
var rawStr = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pm.environment.get('VAR1'))
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(rawStr)
console.log(`Encrypted value: ${base64}`)

//Decrypt
var parsedWord = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64)
var parsedStr = parsedWord.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
console.log(`Decrypted value: ${parsedStr}`)
```

[image: Postman Request]

Postman Console output:

[image: Postman Console]

This is probably not the exact solution that you need but hopefully this brings you closer to achieving what you need to do.

Comment: ,This helped me out!  window.btoa does not work with Postman app. It can work with Postman Extension of Chrome. Using your solution, I can get base64 decoding on app now. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I see that, in the answer given by @danny-dainton he is importing a JS library. That is unnecessary.

**You can just use the btoa and atob functions.** [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp)

In postman this would be (In your `Tests` / `Pre-request Script` tab)

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var encodedValue = btoa(str);
var decodedValue = atob(encodedValue);
```

So in your case to decode `{ "VAR1": "313", "VAR2": "33344", "VAR3": "rovkssj", }`
you can just do

```
var str = "{ \"VAR1\": \"313\", \"VAR2\": \"33344\", \"VAR3\": \"rovkssj\", }";
var encodedValue = btoa(str);
```

PS: I just want to add that your JSON `{ "VAR1": "313", "VAR2": "33344", "VAR3": "rovkssj", }` is not valid as there is an extra `,` at the end.

Comment: Thank for contributing your answer. It helped me with my specific scenario.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)